# Android Java how to stop the code from execute like break point

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database

My code retrieving on `AsyncTask` data from cloud database.

I have notice, if I am putting break point(while debugging), My code runs ok, the data received and then my code manipulate that data.

If I am not using any break point my array is null, the code did not wait for the data to arrive.

I have tried,

```
Thread.sleep(timeInMills);
```

and

```
SystemClock.sleep(timeInMills);
```

but this did not help, It seems to stop the entire Thread.
Is there a way for me to stop the code the same way break point does for a second or two.

Again this does not effect my UI Thread as this run in AsyncTask.

Comment: [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - `onPostExecute` should continue with the result. That is the meaning of _asynchroneous_, a callback at another time.

Comment: I am using onPostExcute but this time it is not helpful as the inbackground  sending the array empty.

Comment: Please share the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, we're just guessing at what you're trying.

Comment: `I have notice, if I am putting break point(while debugging), My code runs ok` IMO I think you are asking to solve a problem using another problem, this could be a flag that your implementation must be changed right away. But before that please show some actual useful snippet.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced a similar situation

if you send the result array to an adapter or a function make it execute at the end of  `onPostExecute` method , as before that your data Array would be empty

Comment: The logic goes like this in bacground.
1. query the firebase database 28 queries 
2. Doing logic compare the queries results.
3. write the results to a file.
4. read the results from the file to array.
5.Send the array results to onPostExecute.
6. Start new activity to the results.
The problem seems to be that the code try to read the results file before the code write the file (As the Firebase queries are taking time)
Both are running in the doingInBackground

Comment: 06:43:43.680  The read response is: => empty
06:43:45.006  The write response is:{"address":"Aharon Boxer 38 ....
I have two seconds difference between read and write

Comment: you can send the results to onPostExcute instead , then write your data to the file and after that read them into the array and then do all your manipulations to it after that . with that u will ensure that your data was written to the file